# SetValidUntilExpires alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What is the alternative for `context.Response.SetValidUntilExpires(true)` in asp.net core?
I checked the headers in an asp.net app, and could not find any changes on setting the flag as `true` or `false`.

```
context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to cache something, do not trust the client. The client can easily ignore it and ask your API again and again.
A better approach would be to use server side caching techniques.

However, it is possible to use the *ResponseCacheAttribute* to solve your issue. Here is an example.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 123, VaryByHeader = "User-Agent")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] {"value1", "value2"};
        }

    }
}
```

In case you are serving static files. Caching is achieved by configuring it in the Startup.cs File of your project.

Here is an example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers; // required

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var durationInSeconds = (int) TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds;
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = context =>
                {
                    context.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
                        $"public,max-age={durationInSeconds}";
                }
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But, I'm dealing with static files. Hence, I have the caching logic as part of a Middleware and not in a controller.

Comment: okay, i updated my answer. hope it helps. could you update your question too and mention the static files =)